# parse errors in css using @media and keyframes

Tags: css, html

```css
/*general CSS setting for generic devices
this will include all hd devices and above*/

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#watchonly {
 display: none;
}


/*animation of the championship logo*/

#champ {
 position: absolute;
 top: 15%;
 right: 20%;
 animation-name: champ;
 animation-duration: 5s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes champ {
 0% {
  right: 20%;
  top: 15%;
 }
 25% {
  right: 22%;
  top: 16%;
 }
 50% {
  right: 20%;
  top: 17%;
 }
 75% {
  right: 19%;
  top: 16%;
 }
 100% {
  right: 20%;
  top: 15%;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}


/*navigation controls*/

nav ul li {
 display: inline;
}

nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
 color: #006734;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 5px 2px;
 padding: 7px 10px 4px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #009340;
}

nav, main, nav ul li a, .twitter-timeline {
 border-radius: 30px;
}

nav {
 background: #6fad60;
 padding: 0 5px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #0e1f0c;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #0e1f0c;
}


/*switching off the watch only text*/

#watchonly {
 display: none;
}

.clear:after {
 content: ".";
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
}

body {
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #f8f8f8;
 background-color: #bcbcbc;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/*the default font*/

h1, h2, h3 {
 font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 color: #00923f;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 35px;
 padding: 3px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
 font-family: forte, "Myriad Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 2px;
}

img {
 width: auto;
 height: 100%;
}

p {
 line-height: 120%;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
}

main .line {
 background-color: #15242a;
 border-bottom-color: #204656;
 margin: 3px;
}

.line {
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #24404c;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #416371;
 margin: 2px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

footer .line {
 margin: 2px;
}


/*Main page size*/

#page {
 width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}

main {
 background-color: #006634;
 margin: 2px;
 padding: 20px;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #001f10;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

footer {
 color: #000000;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 10px;
}

footer a, footer a:visited {
 color: #6fad60;
 background-color: #006634;
 padding: 2px 4px;
}

footer a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #000000;
}

footer a.up {
 float: right;
}


/*control of the twitter frame*/

.twitter-timeline {
 border: 3px solid #00943f;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#twitter-widget-0 {
 height: 500px !important;
 min-height: 500px !important;
}

a, a:visited {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}

a:hover {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

a img {
 border: none;
}

iframe {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
}


/*turning off the image and allowing the iframe to show*/

#whensmall {
 display: none;
}


/*control of the form*/

form {
 padding: 20px;
}

textarea {
 height: 300px;
 width: 275px;
}

input {
 padding-left: 90px;
}


/*control of map iframe*/

.map {
 width: 300px;
 height: 350px;
}


/*a very simple default for future use on limited screens 
ie watches or screens under 300px square*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 /*Main page size*/
 #page {
  width: 290px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 }
 /*switching off most of the page contect*/
 #watchonly {
  font-style: oblique;
  display: flex;
  color: black;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
 }
 footer, nav, h1, h2, h3, p, #main, .line, #champ {
  display: none;
 }
 img {
  float: left;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 60px;
  max-width: 280px;
  max-height: 200px;
 }
}


/*Control of elements for small phone screens over 300 wide and below 500px
This has been left to action of the use in portrait also*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 500px) {
 /*switching off the iframe, large champions image and the watch only text*/
 #whenbig {
  display: none;
 }
 #whensmall {
  display: none;
 }
 #watchonly {
  display: none;
 }
 /*animation of the championship logo*/
 #champ {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 55px;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: champ1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
 @keyframes champ1 {
  0% {
   right: 0%;
   top: 0%;
  }
  25% {
   right: 2%;
   top: 2%;
  }
  50% {
   right: 4%;
   top: 1%;
   transform: rotateY(160deg);
  }
  75% {
   right: 2%;
   top: 2%;
  }
  100% {
   right: 0%;
   top: 0%;
  }
 }
 ul {
  padding: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
 }
 nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
  color: #006734;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 /*change of the navigation*/
 nav ul li {
  display: inline;
 }
 nav {
  position: relative;
 }
 /*Main page size*/
 #page {
  width: 295px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 }
 /*map size change*/
 .map {
  width: 260px;
 }
 /*switching the twitter so as to leave only a link*/
 #twitter-widget-0 {
  height: 45px !important;
  min-height: 5px !important;
 }
 .twitter-timeline {
  border: 3px solid #00943f;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
 }
 /*edit of the font sizes*/
 h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 2px;
 }
 /*edit to control a smaller form*/
 form {
  padding: 30px;
 }
 textarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 185px;
 }
 input {
  padding-left: 0px;
 }
}


/*Control of elements for larger phone screens/small tablets over 500 wide and below 700px
This has been left to action of the use in portrait also*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 700px) {
 /*switching off the iframe, switching on the large champions
image and off the watch only text*/
 #whenbig {
  display: none;
 }
 #whensmall {
  display: inline;
 }
 #watchonly {
  display: none;
 }
 /*edit of the font sizes*/
 h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 h3 {
  font-size: 26px;
 }
 /*Main page size*/
 #page {
  width: 490px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 }
 /*change of the navigation*/
 nav ul li {
  display: block;
 }
 /*animation of the championship logo*/
 #champ {
  position: fixed;
  top: 36%;
  right: 0%;
  height: 75px;
  animation-name: Champ2;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
 }
 @keyframes Champ2 {
  0% {
   right: 00%;
   top: 36%;
  }
  5% {
   right: 05%;
   top: 29%;
  }
  10% {
   right: 10%;
   top: 20%;
  }
  15% {
   right: 15%;
   top: 13%;
  }
  20% {
   right: 20%;
   top: 07%;
  }
  25% {
   right: 25%;
   top: 05%;
  }
  30% {
   right: 30%;
   top: 07%;
  }
  35% {
   right: 35%;
   top: 13%;
  }
  40% {
   right: 40%;
   top: 20%;
  }
  45% {
   right: 45%;
   top: 29%;
  }
  50% {
   right: 50%;
   top: 36%;
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  55% {
   right: 45%;
   top: 43%;
  }
  60% {
   right: 40%;
   top: 52%;
  }
  65% {
   right: 35%;
   top: 59%;
  }
  70% {
   right: 30%;
   top: 65%;
  }
  75% {
   right: 25%;
   top: 66%;
  }
  80% {
   right: 20%;
   top: 65%;
  }
  85% {
   right: 15%;
   top: 59%;
  }
  90% {
   right: 10%;
   top: 52%;
  }
  95% {
   right: 05%;
   top: 43%;
  }
  100% {
   right: 00%;
   top: 36%;
  }
 }
 /*control of the twitter frame size*/
 #twitter-widget-0 {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: 600px !important;
 }
 /*control of the map iframe size*/
 .map {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
 }
 /*edit to control a smaller form*/
 form {
  padding: 20px;
 }
 textarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 185px;
 }
 input {
  padding-left: 0px;
 }
}


/*Control of elements for large phone screens/sd tablets over 700 wide and below 900px
This has been left to action of the use in portrait also*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px) {
 /*switching off the iframe, switching on the large champions
image and off the watch only text*/
 #whenbig {
  display: none;
 }
 #whensmall {
  display: inline;
  padding: 100px;
 }
 #watchonly {
  display: none;
 }
 /*Font size control*/
 h1 {
  font-size: 44px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px;
 }
 h3 {
  font-size: 38px;
 }
 /*Main page size*/
 #page {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
 }
 /*edit of the navigation bar*/
 nav ul li {
  display: block;
 }
 /*Animation of the championship logo*/
 #champ {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 30vw;
  animation-name: champ3;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
 }
 @keyframes champ3 {
  0% {
   right: 30vw;
   top: 10px;
  }
  10% {
   right: 25vw;
   top: 25px;
  }
  18% {
   right: 25vw;
   top: 40px;
  }
  24% {
   right: 30vw;
   top: 55px;
  }
  32% {
   right: 35vw;
   top: 70px;
  }
  40% {
   right: 35vw;
   top: 85px;
  }
  48% {
   right: 30vw;
   top: 100px;
   transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
  56% {
   right: 25vw;
   top: 85px;
  }
  64% {
   right: 25vw;
   top: 70px;
  }
  72% {
   right: 30vw;
   top: 55px;
  }
  80% {
   right: 35vw;
   top: 40px;
  }
  90% {
   right: 35vw;
   top: 25px;
  }
  100% {
   right: 30vw;
   top: 10px;
  }
 }
 /*twitter frame size*/
 #twitter-widget-0 {
  width: 300px !important;
  min-height: 5px !important;
 }
 /*map iframe size*/
 .map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
 }
 /*form size controls*/
 form {
  padding: 50px;
 }
 textarea {
  height: 300px;
  width: 245px;
 }
 input {
  padding-left: 60px;
 }
}
```

I have been trying to validate my website via the w3c validator.

the html5 passes yet the CSS will not.
I receive parse errors (x6) at keyframes.

I have tried various french bracket arrangments as it would appear that the differing ones get picked up incorrectly

I have included my CSS
any help is much appreciated

This is my first attempt at html and css

```css
/*general CSS setting for generic devices
this will include all hd devices and above*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#watchonly {
    display: none;
}


/*animation of the championship logo*/

#champ {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    right: 20%;
    animation-name: champ;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes champ {
    0% {
        right: 20%;
        top: 15%;
    }
    25% {
        right: 22%;
        top: 16%;
    }
    50% {
        right: 20%;
        top: 17%;
    }
    75% {
        right: 19%;
        top: 16%;
    }
    100% {
        right: 20%;
        top: 15%;
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}


/*navigation controls*/

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
    color: #006734;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px 2px;
    padding: 7px 10px 4px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #009340;
}

nav, main, nav ul li a, .twitter-timeline {
    border-radius: 30px;
}

nav {
    background: #6fad60;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #0e1f0c;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #0e1f0c;
}


/*switching off the watch only text*/

#watchonly {
    display: none;
}

.clear:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}

body {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #f8f8f8;
    background-color: #bcbcbc;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/*the default font*/

h1, h2, h3 {
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: #00923f;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
    font-family: forte, "Myriad Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 2px;
}

img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

p {
    line-height: 120%;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

main .line {
    background-color: #15242a;
    border-bottom-color: #204656;
    margin: 3px;
}

.line {
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #24404c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #416371;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer .line {
    margin: 2px;
}


/*Main page size*/

#page {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

main {
    background-color: #006634;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #001f10;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

footer {
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

footer a, footer a:visited {
    color: #6fad60;
    background-color: #006634;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}

footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
}

footer a.up {
    float: right;
}


/*control of the twitter frame*/

.twitter-timeline {
    border: 3px solid #00943f;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#twitter-widget-0 {
    height: 500px !important;
    min-height: 500px !important;
}

a, a:visited {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a img {
    border: none;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}


/*turning off the image and allowing the iframe to show*/

#whensmall {
    display: none;
}


/*control of the form*/

form {
    padding: 20px;
}

textarea {
    height: 300px;
    width: 275px;
}

input {
    padding-left: 90px;
}


/*control of map iframe*/

.map {
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
}


/*a very simple default for future use on limited screens 
ie watches or screens under 300px square*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    /*Main page size*/
    #page {
        width: 290px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    /*switching off most of the page contect*/
    #watchonly {
        font-style: oblique;
        display: flex;
        color: black;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
    }
    footer, nav, h1, h2, h3, p, #main, .line, #champ {
        display: none;
    }
    img {
        float: left;
        float: right;
        padding-top: 60px;
        max-width: 280px;
        max-height: 200px;
    }
}


/*Control of elements for small phone screens over 300 wide and below 500px
This has been left to action of the use in portrait also*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    /*switching off the iframe, large champions image and the watch only text*/
    #whenbig {
        display: none;
    }
    #whensmall {
        display: none;
    }
    #watchonly {
        display: none;
    }
    /*animation of the championship logo*/
    #champ {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        right: 0%;
        height: 55px;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-name: champ1;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-delay: 2s;
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
    @keyframes champ1 {
        0% {
            right: 0%;
            top: 0%;
        }
        25% {
            right: 2%;
            top: 2%;
        }
        50% {
            right: 4%;
            top: 1%;
            transform: rotateY(160deg);
        }
        75% {
            right: 2%;
            top: 2%;
        }
        100% {
            right: 0%;
            top: 0%;
        }
    }
    ul {
        padding: 0%;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline;
    }
    nav ul li a, nav ul li a:visited {
        color: #006734;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0px 0px;
        padding: 10px 5px 10px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    /*change of the navigation*/
    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
    }
    nav {
        position: relative;
    }
    /*Main page size*/
    #page {
        width: 295px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    /*map size change*/
    .map {
        width: 260px;
    }
    /*switching the twitter so as to leave only a link*/
    #twitter-widget-0 {
        height: 45px !important;
        min-height: 5px !important;
    }
    .twitter-timeline {
        border: 3px solid #00943f;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
    }
    /*edit of the font sizes*/
    h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 2px;
    }
    /*edit to control a smaller form*/
    form {
        padding: 30px;
    }
    textarea {
        height: 300px;
        width: 185px;
    }
    input {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}


/*Control of elements for larger phone screens/small tablets over 500 wide and below 700px
This has been left to action of the use in portrait also*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 700px) {
    /*switching off the iframe, switching on the large champions
image and off the watch only text*/
    #whenbig {
        display: none;
    }
    #whensmall {
        display: inline;
    }
    #watchonly {
        display: none;
    }
    /*edit of the font sizes*/
    h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    /*Main page size*/
    #page {
        width: 490px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    /*change of the navigation*/
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    /*animation of the championship logo*/
    #champ {
        position: fixed;
        top: 36%;
        right: 0%;
        height: 75px;
        animation-name: Champ2;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    @keyframes Champ2 {
        0% {
            right: 00%;
            top: 36%;
        }
        5% {
            right: 05%;
            top: 29%;
        }
        10% {
            right: 10%;
            top: 20%;
        }
        15% {
            right: 15%;
            top: 13%;
        }
        20% {
            right: 20%;
            top: 07%;
        }
        25% {
            right: 25%;
            top: 05%;
        }
        30% {
            right: 30%;
            top: 07%;
        }
        35% {
            right: 35%;
            top: 13%;
        }
        40% {
            right: 40%;
            top: 20%;
        }
        45% {
            right: 45%;
            top: 29%;
        }
        50% {
            right: 50%;
            top: 36%;
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
        }
        55% {
            right: 45%;
            top: 43%;
        }
        60% {
            right: 40%;
            top: 52%;
        }
        65% {
            right: 35%;
            top: 59%;
        }
        70% {
            right: 30%;
            top: 65%;
        }
        75% {
            right: 25%;
            top: 66%;
        }
        80% {
            right: 20%;
            top: 65%;
        }
        85% {
            right: 15%;
            top: 59%;
        }
        90% {
            right: 10%;
            top: 52%;
        }
        95% {
            right: 05%;
            top: 43%;
        }
        100% {
            right: 00%;
            top: 36%;
        }
    }
    /*control of the twitter frame size*/
    #twitter-widget-0 {
        width: 100px !important;
        height: 600px !important;
    }
    /*control of the map iframe size*/
    .map {
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    /*edit to control a smaller form*/
    form {
        padding: 20px;
    }
    textarea {
        height: 300px;
        width: 185px;
    }
    input {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}


/*Control of elements for large phone screens/sd tablets over 700 wide and below 900px
This has been left to action of the use in portrait also*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    /*switching off the iframe, switching on the large champions
image and off the watch only text*/
    #whenbig {
        display: none;
    }
    #whensmall {
        display: inline;
        padding: 100px;
    }
    #watchonly {
        display: none;
    }
    /*Font size control*/
    h1 {
        font-size: 44px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    h3 {
        font-size: 38px;
    }
    /*Main page size*/
    #page {
        width: 700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    /*edit of the navigation bar*/
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
    }
    /*Animation of the championship logo*/
    #champ {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 30vw;
        animation-name: champ3;
        animation-duration: 5s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-delay: 2s;
    }
    @keyframes champ3 {
        0% {
            right: 30vw;
            top: 10px;
        }
        10% {
            right: 25vw;
            top: 25px;
        }
        18% {
            right: 25vw;
            top: 40px;
        }
        24% {
            right: 30vw;
            top: 55px;
        }
        32% {
            right: 35vw;
            top: 70px;
        }
        40% {
            right: 35vw;
            top: 85px;
        }
        48% {
            right: 30vw;
            top: 100px;
            transform: rotateY(360deg);
        }
        56% {
            right: 25vw;
            top: 85px;
        }
        64% {
            right: 25vw;
            top: 70px;
        }
        72% {
            right: 30vw;
            top: 55px;
        }
        80% {
            right: 35vw;
            top: 40px;
        }
        90% {
            right: 35vw;
            top: 25px;
        }
        100% {
            right: 30vw;
            top: 10px;
        }
    }
    /*twitter frame size*/
    #twitter-widget-0 {
        width: 300px !important;
        min-height: 5px !important;
    }
    /*map iframe size*/
    .map {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    /*form size controls*/
    form {
        padding: 50px;
    }
    textarea {
        height: 300px;
        width: 245px;
    }
    input {
        padding-left: 60px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule at-rules (`@...`) are invalid inside the `@media` rules (*like the `@keyframes` rules*).

So you might have to define the animations outside of the media queries and just assign them to the elements in the media query.

---

If you put your css in an editor that can auto-indent it you will see the problems

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  /*switching off the iframe, large champions image and the watch only text*/
  #whenbig {
    display: none;
  }
  #whensmall {
    display: none;
  }
  #watchonly {
    display: none;
  }
  /*animation of the championship logo*/
  #champ {
    position: absolute;
    @keyframes champ1 {
      25% {
        right: 2%;
        top: 2%;
      }
      50% {
        right: 4%;
        top: 1%;
        75% {
          right: 2%;
          top: 2%;
        }
        100% {
          right: 0%;
          top: 0%;
        }
      }
      ul {
        padding: 0%;
        nav ul li a,
        nav ul li a:visited {
          color: #006734;
          /*change of the navigation*/
          nav ul li {
            display: inline;
          }
          nav {
            position: relative;
          }
          /*Main page size*/
          #page {
            width: 295px;
            /*map size change*/
            .map {
              width: 260px;
            }
            /*switching the twitter so as to leave only a link*/
            #twitter-widget-0 {
              height: 45px !important;
              .twitter-timeline {
                border: 3px solid #00943f;
                /*edit of the font sizes*/
                h1 {
```

As you can see the code is missing some `}` and thus wrong nesting is happening.

Comment: very embarrassing on my first ever post/question. some of the code was hidden by the program and didn't get copied. I had checked the code regarding the nesting numerous times and was so embarrassed. i have re-inserted the code. i will look at the nesting again though :) thanks

Comment: it worked. A lot of faffing later (some didn't make sense at all) it works. thank you ever so much

Answer (score 1):

Your `@keyframe` cannot been inside your block `#champ` it must been like this:
`

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position :relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    25%  {top: 200px;}
    75%  {top: 50px}
    100% {top: 100px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;}
    25%  {top: 200px;}
    75%  {top: 50px}
    100% {top: 100px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The @keyframes rule is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

`

See. `mymove` is variable and it's located at the top level as varialbe

Comment: I think I'm going crazy looking at this code again and again. looking at the above I cant see where I'm going wrong. the #champ is referring to a div tag and I can't see that my @keyframes are in the #champ block. i am really lost :(

Answer (score 0):

These validators are not end-all be-all authorities on valid html and css. If it works, and the browser doesn't throw any errors then you're fine.

Comment: i am trying to validate this as part of an assignment. One of the conditions is that it validates unfortunately.

Comment: it does work and doesn't trip up. admittedly some browsers ignore parts but that IE for you.....

Comment: @BobMonk have you tried making a small, simple dummy file with basic css animation and seeing if that passes first? Don't waste your time tweaking a giant file until you know this can actually pass.

Comment: The first part does pass upto line 209. Then it goes bad. I incrementally put in the sections and wanted to see if the pass. One media query at a time passes. One after another doesnt